# Error with a excluded dependency in Spring Boot project: exclusion.artifactId with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern

Tags: quartz-scheduler, dependency-management, parent-pom, spring-boot-starter

If I want to build my project with maven package, I get the warning from Maven:
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for

> ch.mobi.ama:logcollector:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
> 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId'
> for org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar with value '*' does not match a
> valid id pattern. @
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.6.RELEASE,
> c:\ieu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom,
> line 2619, column 25

I've tried older Spring Boot versions. Version 2.1.5 had the same problem. With 2.1.4 there is no warning.
In line 2619 of the specified file `spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom` there is actually the following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Since the given code comes from Spring Boot, I can't influence it and have a bad feeling. Will my project be properly built? Do I have to go back to version 2.1.4? Do I have to report the problem to Spring Boot?
What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a maven new feature. Upgrade your maven to some version > 3.2.1.

https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html